# Unable to resolve the value for property 'CosmosDBAttribute.ConnectionStringSetting'

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have developed simple Service Bus Trigger with CosmosDB Output with Visual Studio. Connection strings of Service Bus and CosmosDB are defined in local.settings.json. 
Code is fully function locally. Now I have Zip Published Function(C#) to Azure.

I'm getting Error:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Function1'. 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Unable to resolve the value for property 
'CosmosDBAttribute.ConnectionStringSetting'.
```

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to  include both your code and your error message as properly-formatted text. [This meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) offers insight into why code and other text shouldn't be published as an image.

Answer (score 7):

The error tells you need to add the settings on Azure.

azure function on azure is different from azure functions on local. on local the settings is in the local.settings.json. But on azure it is in the Configuration.(Even if you deploy the local.settings.json, the function will read env settings from Congfiguration)

[image]

[image]

And dont forget to save your edit.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically update such values from local.settings.json to application settings during deployment? I read that they have to be part of POM.xml but how do we get it into that file?

Comment: yes, you can upload your local.settings.json file with the code, by default that file didnt gets uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in local when running the azure function. My connection string was not accepted because the AccountKey was considered part of the URL of AccountEndpoint, and I gave space between the endpoint of AccountKey and AccountEndpoint.

"connectionStringSetting": "AccountEndpoint=;  AccountKey=;"

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "myCosmosDb": "AccountEndpoint=https://mycosmoscosmosdb.documents.azure.com:443/; AccountKey=asd4ph1omRg9Rn4dlj7h1f7XqUdO1mHJcpG9rN1XECSO4P6LKorDXjdqK8VTookKvbKXjPTulpEsdfdsbwg==;"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my the extension was missing in host.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "cosmosDB": {
            "connectionMode": "Gateway",
            "protocol": "Https",
            "leaseOptions": {
                "leasePrefix": "prefix1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here the reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-output?tabs=csharp#hostjson-settings